# This page contains both secure and nonsecure items and iframes

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-6

IE 6.0 is giving me the message "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items" because I have iframes on my page (for the combo box bug). I have tried pointing to a few different things in the src but I can't seem to get rid of this message without putting in a blank html page, which I would like to avoid so there isn't a server call. Is there any solution? I suppose I could use the blank page and have the cache never expire on it possibly if there is no other choice and that should avoid the server trip?

Comment: You've tried a relative path in the SRC attribute?

Comment: I have a working solution below. I didn't want to use a relative path to anything so I could avoid a server trip for a empty iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I set the src to javascript:false; it works. I found this by examining what the yui library uses.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a few ways to solve this using javascript. The `javascript:false;` method solves the "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items" problem but it also outputs the text "false" into the iframe which is undesirable if you want it to look like an empty iframe.

Another approach is to set the src attribute to `javascript:'';` which solves the issue stated above.